# How can you store credentials in a JNDI lookup?

Tags: glassfish, jndi

I have an app with several `properties` files, and I was curious if it'd be easier to store these `username`/`password`/`server-url-to-login-to` combos in a JNDI lookup instead of this clear text file in a .jar.

There are a couple questions:

1. Can you store credentials that aren't databases using JNDI?
2. How do you configure a new JNDI resource to store these properties?
3. How would you retrieve these properties from the resource?

Most of the documentation I read was how to set up JNDI for database connections, and for my use, I'm not connecting to **any** databases, but instead different kinds of web services using different authentication schemes (SOAP user/password in request message, HTTP Basic, headers, SSL, etc.).

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497468/inject-a-file-using-resource-and-jndi-in-jee6/18550778#18550778

Answer (score 3):

The answers to your questions:

> 1. Can you store credentials that aren't databases using JNDI?

Yes.

> 1. How do you configure a new JNDI resource to store these properties?

If you are using Glassfish 2 you have to create your custom `PropertiesObjectFactory` class to handle `JNDI` properties of `java.util.Porperties`.

For e.g. `PropertiesObjectFactory` class could look like this:

```
public class PropertiesObjectFactory implements Serializable, ObjectFactory {

    public static final String FILE_PROPERTY_NAME = "org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory.fileName";

    public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable<?, ?> environment)
            throws Exception {
        Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
        Enumeration<RefAddr> refAddrs = ref.getAll();

        String fileName = null;
        Properties fileProperties = new Properties();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        while (refAddrs.hasMoreElements()) {
            RefAddr addr = refAddrs.nextElement();
            String type = addr.getType();
            String value = (String) addr.getContent();

            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(FILE_PROPERTY_NAME)) {
                fileName = value;
            } else {
                properties.put(type, value);
            }
        }

        if (fileName != null) {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            if (!file.isAbsolute()) {
                file = new File(System.getProperty("com.sun.aas.installRoot") + File.separator + fileName);
            }
            try {
                if (file.exists()) {
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        if (fileName.toUpperCase().endsWith("XML")) {
                            fileProperties.loadFromXML(fis);
                        } else {
                            fileProperties.load(fis);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        throw new IOException("IO Exception during properties load : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        fileProperties.putAll(properties);
        return fileProperties;
    }
}
```

Make a jar of that class, add it into glassfish global classpath. It would be: `/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib` and then you can specify it as a factory class in your `JNDI` properties configuration.

Glassfish 3 already have properties factory class. It is set into: `org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory`.

Open glassfish admin console and navigate to: Resources -> JNDI -> Custom Resources, click "New", provide a JNDI name, for e.g: `jndi/credentials`, choose a resource type `java.util.Properties`, specify Factory class: `org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory`, then click "Add property", specify name for e.g: `testUsernameName` and in value column `testUsernameValue`. Click OK and that is all, you have configured `JNDI` resource. You can add as many properties as you like to this: `jndi/credentials` resource.

Don't forget to restart app server when you done creating resources.

> 1. How would you retrieve these properties from the resource?

```
public Properties getProperties(String jndiName) {
    Properties properties = null;
    try {
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        properties = (Properties) context.lookup(jndiName);
        context.close();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Naming error occurred while initializing properties from JNDI.", e);
        return null;
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Example how to get the property:

```
String username = someInstance.getProperties("jndi/credentials").getProperty("testUsernameName");
```

Your `username` would be: `testUsernameValue`.

When you call this method in your application provide a `JNDI` name you configured in your application server: `jndi/credentials`. If you have mapped resources in deployment descriptor you have to use: `java:comp/env/jndi/credentials`.

If you want to do the same using `Spring`:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="credentials"
                 jndi-name="jndi/credentials"/>
```

Well I hope thats it. Hope this helps.

Comment: i know this is old, but i hope you would still know the answer as i am trying to recreate this on glassfish4.1. Which .jars should i be using for the context and properties? or are they included in a predefined package?