# junit glassfish v3 oracle db

Tags: oracle, junit, glassfish

trying to write ejb3 junit on netbeans8
we use weblogic 12c but i cant get their embedded container so gave up and trying glassfish

it goes further but one thing bizzar is, even though my persistence xml uses oracle settings, it fires derby and says my schema/tables are not there

I am **NOT** trying to use derby

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
>       <persistence-unit name="ACP-warPU" transaction-type="JTA">
>           <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
>           <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
>           <shared-cache-mode>ALL</shared-cache-mode>
>           <properties>
>               <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
>               <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger"/>
>               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db11g"/>
>               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="spa"/>
>               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
>               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="spa"/>
>           </properties>
>       </persistence-unit>
>   </persistence>`

```
Map<String, Object> p = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    File[] modules = {
        new File("target/test-classes"),
        new File("target/classes")

    };
    p.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, modules);
    p.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.installation.root", "/target/gfv3");

    ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p);
    ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();
    ejbFacade = (AllocnGrpFacade) ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/AllocnGrpFacade");


Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'SPA' does not exist
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: version info - jdk 1.6 , glassfish 3.1.2.2 - java ee 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you need glassfish domain setup even for embedded container

I wish I can do this with code, and not with generated garbage, but for now this is how I did it

solved see

[Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967291/caused-by-javax-naming-namenotfoundexception-pools/23020753#23020753)